# Why my retrieved image from firebase is not shown/not visible in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to upload image to the firebase Storage and firebase realtime database and view it in a recyclerview. The image is also being include text where the user could specify the title of their image. When trying to show the uploaded images in recyclerview, only the text is visible but the image is not shown.Below is my recyclerview adapter:-[firebase realtime database storing the image url and name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYyQX.png)

```
`package com.example.fieldhockeybooking;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;


public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<AdvertUploadInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;

    public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<AdvertUploadInfo> TempList) {

        this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AdvertUploadInfo UploadInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

        holder.imageNameTextView.setText(UploadInfo.getImageName());

        //Loading image from Glide library.
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(UploadInfo.getImageURL())
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView imageNameTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            imageNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
        }
    }
}
`
```

[this is what shown from my android apps when i try to show all uploaded images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdkg6.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to security rules with `match /{allPaths=**}` to indicate that public read and write access is allowed on all paths:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implement this rules on my firebase storage rules but the images is still not showing up. Previously I am using this rules:  service firebase.storage {
  match /b/field-hockey-booking-4b52a.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true; 
    }
  }
}

Comment: check your log if you find any because of not showing images then share it with us.

Comment: "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout." I found this in my logcat. Is this the problem that affects my image not shown on recyclerview?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set rules in firebase realtime database to retrieve the images and display in recyclerview.
Check this link 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: I had implement rules in my database which i set to allow read,write. but the images still did not displayed in my recyclerview, but only the name of the image is displayed.